# Spring Transaction with dependent insertions not working

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, foreign-keys, transactional

Here's my code:

Entities:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    Long aId;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    Long bId;
    Long aId;
    ...
}
```

Service:

```
@Transactional
public void multiInsert() {
    A a = createA();
    aRepository.save(a);

    B b = createBFromA();
    bRepository.save(b);
}
```

When I am try to do `bRepository.save()`, it is failing with the following error:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`b`, CONSTRAINT `a_to_b` FOREIGN KEY (`aId`) REFERENCES `a` (`aId`))

My guess is `a` is not persisted before we are trying to save `b` due to which the foreign key constraint is failing.

I am aware that for foreign key, I should use @JoinColumns. But is there a way to make it work without that.